# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise offline installation stuck

Tags: visual-studio, enterprise, visual-studio-2017

I had to disconnect my laptop from the internet for some time (before disconnecting the offline installation was working just fine and had already downloaded 11.6GB). When I got back I ran the   `vs_enterprise.exe --layout C:\vs2017offline --lang en-US`   command again but now it gets stuck on

=> `Layout operation correlation: {"id":"5c09fc12-236c-4c7e-9a8e-7d24500b9e1d"}`

I checked my error log file and it is empty.
Below are my log files. I can't understand why this is happening, so any help will be appreciated.

=>`[29e8:000f][2017-03-18T10:56:51] Download requested: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833502`

=>`[29e8:000c][2017-03-18T10:56:51] Download requested: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833501`

=>`[29e8:0012][2017-03-18T10:56:51] Attempting download 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833502' using engine 'WebClient'`

=>`[29e8:0013][2017-03-18T10:56:51] Attempting download 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=833501' using engine 'WebClient'`

Comment: It tries to download `android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86.zip` and `android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64.zip`. I'd try and see if those files do exist on your harddisk or if, inside the cache directory either of these directories (`AndroidNDK_R12B,version=12.1.5,chip=x64` or `AndroidNDK_R12B,version=12.1.5,chip=x86` exist. If they do, delete them (zip files) or rename them (directories) and try that command again.